# Phone freezes when listening for incoming sms's

Tags: blackberry, sms

Why does the following code freeze all operations on the phone? The app reads the incoming sms's, but the app doesn't open. Right after the app is clicked, the phone freezes. What am I doing wrong. I would appreciate any help.

```java
try {  
   //A DatagramConnection is created to listen for any incoming sms's.
   DatagramConnection _dc =
      (DatagramConnection)Connector.open("sms://"); 

   Datagram d = _dc.newDatagram(_dc.getMaximumLength());  

   _dc.receive(d);                             
   byte[] bytes = d.getData();
   String address = d.getAddress(); //The address of the sms is put on a string.
   String msg = new String(bytes); //The body of the sms is put on a string. 
} catch (Exception me) {

}
```

Comment: Try to run code inside thread

Comment: Can you please provide me with a code sample on how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run your code inside thread (this is worst code that I wrote):

```
new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        DatagramConnection _dc =
        (DatagramConnection)Connector.open("sms://"); //A DatagramConnection is created to listen for any incoming sms's.

        Datagram d = _dc.newDatagram(_dc.getMaximumLength());  

        _dc.receive(d);                             
        byte[] bytes = d.getData();
        String address = d.getAddress(); //The address of the sms is put on a string.
        String msg = new String(bytes); //The body of the sms is put on a string.
    }
}.start();
```